# In R, find the most times one value repeats in a "column" of values

Tags: r, dplyr

The data below is for one starting pitcher who had 18 starts in one season.
Starts beginning with "W" means the starter won the game.
Starts beginning with "L" means the starter lost the game.
A start with "nd" (no-decision) means the starter neither won nor lost the game.

**Input**

```
game_num <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
starts <- c("L(0-1)", "L(0-2)", "nd", "nd", "nd", "L(0-3)", "L(0-4)", "W(1-4)", "nd","L(1-5)", "W(2-5)", "W(3-5)", "W(4-5)", "W(5-5)", "W(6-5)", "nd", "L(6-6)", "W(7-6)")
```

I need to know what was the most consecutive "no-decision" games the pitcher had in a season.

For the above data, the answer is 3 as "nd" appears in three consecutive starts.

How can I do that in R (preferably using dplyr)?

I have reviewed other answers in stackoverflow, but did not see one that matched my situation. If I missed one that does, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R version. You can use `rle` to get the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector, then the maximum length (where the value is "nd") is the desired number of consecutive starts with no-decision.

```
s_rle <- rle(starts)
s_len <- s_rle$lengths[s_rle$values == "nd"]
max(s_len)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` within `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(game_num = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18),
                     starts = c("L(0-1)", "L(0-2)", "nd", "nd", "nd", "L(0-3)", "L(0-4)", "W(1-4)", "nd","L(1-5)", "W(2-5)", "W(3-5)", "W(4-5)", "W(5-5)", "W(6-5)", "nd", "L(6-6)", "W(7-6)"))

mode <- function(x){
  which.max(tabulate(x))
}

df %>%
  mutate(value = rleid(starts)) %>%
  filter(starts == "nd") %>%
  summarise(value = mode(value))
```